# Laravel 4.2 view:publish from custom location

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, package, view, publish

I'm currently developing a package in L4.2 but I'm not using the workbench I have a complete custom structure.

But now I'm facing the problem that when I execute the artisan command view:publish I get the following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Views not found.
```

It seems like I have to give Laravel the location of my views but I can't find how to do this, so I hope anybody could help me.

```
My views are located at: vendor/package/src/views 
My service provider at: vendor/package/src/serviceprovider.php
```

I also tried to use `php artisan view:publish vendor/package --path="src/views"` but no luck so far.

I hope somebody can help me,
Thanks,
Joren

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan view:publish td/longstack --path="packages/vendorname/packagename/src/views/"
```

Never mind I forgot to specify the folder where alle my packages are located. It works now.